# How can I view the currently played or highlighted note in Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live

I've switched from Logic Pro to to Ableton Live.  A feature I like from Logic that I don't see in Ableton is that Logic tells me what note I'm currently playing when I press on my music keyboard, or when I highlight notes in the piano roll.  Is it possible to see this in Ableton?